# Module 'firebase_core' not found when integrating Firebase in Flutter iOS app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I'm currently working on integrating Firebase into my Flutter application, but I'm facing an issue while trying to build the iOS version of my app. The build error I'm encountering is:

`Module 'firebase_core' not found`

I've followed various references and tutorials to set up Firebase in my Flutter app, and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Here are a few things I've tried:

Ensured that I've added the necessary dependencies for Firebase plugins in my pubspec.yaml file.
Double-checked that I've followed the installation steps correctly, including updating my AppDelegate.swift and Info.plist files.
Cleaned the Xcode build and re-run the build process.
Verified that my Flutter and Dart versions are up-to-date.
Tried running the app on both simulators and real devices.
Despite trying these steps, I'm still stuck with the "Module 'firebase_core' not found" error. Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions to overcome this obstacle.

Thank you in advance!

Platform: Flutter + Dart + iOS

pubspec.yml file:

```js
name: test_2
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htaGv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

do `flutter clean`
get dependencies
remove `podefile.lock` from your ios project and run `pod install` under ios directory .
hope this helps

Comment: I've already done this step

Comment: was it success ? if yes , share the pod install logs, and are you using latest packages ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using latest packages, but no worries, Issue has been drastically resolved by making new project.

Thanks for your valuable inputs.